# "Scoped" make scss files and code not working on single vue component

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuejs2

I'm working on a big Vue project includes a lot of components and my problem is that am trying to include some scss files to make them work in a specific component or specific rout tree (like call it on parent component so it will affect the child's) any way to apply that i use `lang="scss" scoped` but unfortunately i found that the code not worked and all styles destroyed and when i remove "Scoped", it works fine but the styles affect another components and i don't want this happened so this is my way to include files

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
    @import "assets/styles/vl.vendor.scss";
    @import "assets/styles/vl.scss";
</style>
```

I've tried all solutions on stackoverflow but no one worked for me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<style lang="scss" src="assets/styles/vl.vendor.scss" scoped></style>
<style lang="scss" src="assets/styles/vl.scss" scoped></style>
```

If it still doesn't work, it might be because paths don't resolve correctly. You might have to use `src="/assets/styles/..."` or `src="../assets/styles/..."`, depending on how paths resolve in your app.